# I can not save the table changes in swing project

Tags: java, swing, properties, preference, savechanges

I change the table's rows place,and save it. But when I close and open project again it designs the table as it wishes. Is there any idea about saving swing project changes? Any technic,method? Here is my save method.

> public void saveLayoutData(String prePath) {

```
    Properties pMain = new Properties();
    File dirMain = new File(prePath + "DWorkSpacesAll" + ".xml");
    File dirPath = new File(prePath);
    if (!dirPath.exists()) {
        File dirBase = new File("./Preferences");
        dirBase.mkdir();
        dirPath.mkdir();
    }
    if (!dirMain.exists()) {
        try {
            dirMain.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    pMain.put("ShowConfirmationDialog", showConfirmation.toString());
    for (DWorkspace w : workSpaces) {
        try {
            w.setTitle(tabbedPane.getTitleAt(workSpaces.indexOf(w)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }

        pMain.put(w.getPreferenceKey(), w.getTitle());
        File dir = new File(prePath + w.getPreferenceKey() + ".dat");


        try {
            if (!dirPath.exists()) {
                File dirBase = new File("./Preferences");
                dirBase.mkdir();
                dirPath.mkdir();
            }
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.createNewFile();
            }
            w.getDockingManager().
                    saveLayoutDataToFile(dir.getCanonicalPath());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream fosMain = null;
    try {
        fosMain = new FileOutputStream(dirMain.getCanonicalPath());
        pMain.storeToXML(fosMain, "");
        fosMain.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fosMain != null) {
                fosMain.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {

        for (DWorkspace w : workSpaces) {
            File dir = new File(prePath + w.getPreferenceKey() + ".xml");

            Properties p = new Properties();

            for (DIComponent c : w.getComponents()) {

                if (c instanceof DIWithPreferences) {

                    DIWithPreferences cwp = (DIWithPreferences) c;

                    String pref = cwp.getPreferences();

                    if (pref != null) {
                        p.put("_" + w.getPreferenceKey() + "_" + cwp.getKey(), pref);
                    }

                }
            }

            p.put("_" + w.getPreferenceKey() + "_" + "Table1", w.Table1());

            p.put("_" + w.getPreferenceKey() + "_" + "Table2",
                    w.Table2());

            p.put("_" + w.getPreferenceKey() + "_" + "Table3",
                    w.Table3());

            p.put("_" + w.getPreferenceKey() + "_" + "Table4",
                    w.Table4());

            if (w.getPreferenceKey() == null) {
            } else {
                p.put("_" + w.getPreferenceKey() + "_" + "Table5",
                        w.Table5());
            }

            if (w.getPreferenceKey() == null) {
            } else {
                p.put("_" + w.getPreferenceKey() + "_" + "Table6",
                        w.Table6());
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir.getCanonicalPath());
            p.storeToXML(fos, "");
            fos.close();

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might need the code you use to load the preferences / XML as well, as it could quite easily be stalling there. Have you tried writing the data you're saving to console to make sure it's being saved? Is the XML file on disc being populated?

Comment: I have loadLayoutData method. When I changed table's rows place and save it,program makes it randomly I think. How can I prevent that to do. How fills true rows to the table. Thanks